# where clause variable malfunctioning

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to oop environment and there is something that seems to be not right here, I have searched all over but the ones available is the query string is given inside the class.

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    include('../Classes/class.config.php');
    include('../Classes/class.dbActions.php');
    $execute=new execute();
    $execute->select('SELECT * FROM users where username="'.$_POST['search'].'" ');
    $array=$execute->Fetch();
    echo $array['chasisNo'].'<br/>';
}
```

when I change:

```
$execute->select('SELECT * FROM users where username="'.$_POST['search'].'" ');
```

to this

```
$execute->select('SELECT * FROM users ');
```

It works perfectly by listing the top
Now what's wrong with this code in that even if i pass a string like

```
$execute->select('SELECT * FROM users where username="oketch" ');
```

it does not work

here is the execute class

```
class execute extends db
{
    private $sqlString;
    private $selected;
    private $querySelected;
    public function select($sqlString)
    {
        $connection=$this->getConnection();
        $this->querySelected=$connection->query($sqlString);
        if($this->querySelected->num_rows>0) {
            $this->Fetch();
        }
        else {
            echo'No Data Available';
        }   
    }   

    public function Fetch() {
        return $this->querySelected->fetch_array();
    }
```

Comment: Might have something to do with this class `execute`.

Comment: how come coz it works fine without the where cause

Comment: function select() already calls function Fetch() (but doesn't return it), so if you select one specific record, that record is lost. The first record of the result is always lost.

Comment: then how should i do it please am new to this

Comment: Well, my opinion is: Drop that class all together. It doesn't look like it provides anything useful. But then again I'm biased against ad-hoc classes `Database`, `Db` or anything with `extends databas-ish-thingy` as can be.

Comment: @VolkerK this is just part of learning this OOP PHP i was used to the normal procedural coding and your advice is really welcomed

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a `$this->Fetch();` inside `select()`. I assume this fetches one row of the result set. You then do a subsequent `$execute->Fetch()` to actually get the result you're looking for.

Without a `WHERE` clause, there will likely be multiple rows. The first result row is consumed and goes into the aether by the `Fetch()` inside `select()`. You then retrieve the *second* row and display it.
With a `WHERE` clause there's only one row which is consumed into the aether, and then there's no actual row left to fetch and display.

Comment: Don't `Fetch()` within `select()`...!? There's no point to doing that.